# This piece of python code should print out some information, but doesn't

Tags: python

The code I'm tring to get should look something like this:

> send: 'GET /xml/atom.xml HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: diveintomark.org\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/1.17\r\n\r\n'
>   reply: 'HTTP/1.1 410 Gone\r\n'
>   header: Date: Sat, 11 Sep 2010 11:47:19 GMT
>   header: Server: Apache
>   header: Content-Length: 307
>   header: Connection: close
>   header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

The code I'm typing in doesn't work. Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with it:

```
import httplib, urllib2

httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1 
request = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.co.uk/')  
opener = urllib2.build_opener()   
feeddata = opener.open(request).read()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to format code etc. properly. And please clarify what *doesn't work* mean. Do you get any error?

Comment: It helps if you include what you do get - i.e. how it differs from what you expect. What I get running this code is that `feeddata` contains the entire source code for `www.google.co.uk` - is this what you get?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the example is simply wrong, try this instead:

```
import urllib2

request = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.co.uk/')
http_handler = urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(http_handler)
feeddata = opener.open(request).read()
```

Comment: Bingo. Why are you importing the httplib though? It shouldn't even be necessary.

Comment: Why is there still a httplib import in there? Also, hi WoLpH!

Comment: @Stephen, @ikanobori: Ah yes... I simply modified the original code and forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I got something out of this:

```
httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
request = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.co.uk/')
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
feeddata = opener.open(request).read()
print feeddata
```

Here's what I got:

```
C:\Tools\Python-2.6.1\python.exe "C:/Documents and Settings/Michael/My Documents/Projects/Python/learning/core/src/so.py"
<!doctype html><html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"><title>Google</title><script>window.google={kEI:"GnOLTKeBIIaQeMCv8IgG",kEXPI:"25856,25900,26446",kCSI:{e:"25856,25900,26446",ei:"GnOLTKeBIIaQeMCv8IgG",expi:"25856,25900,26446"},ml:function(){},kHL:"en",time:function(){return(new Date).getTime()},log:function(b,d,c){var a=new Image,e=google,g=e.lc,f=e.li;a.onerror=(a.onload=(a.onabort=function(){delete g[f]}));g[f]=a;c=c||"/gen_204?atyp=i&ct="+b+"&cad="+d+"&zx="+google.time();a.src=c;e.li=f+1},lc:[],li:0,Toolbelt:{}};
window.google.sn="webhp";window.google.timers={load:{t:{start:(new Date).getTime()}}};try{}catch(u){}window.google.jsrt_kill=1;
var _gjwl=location;function _gjuc(){var e=_gjwl.href.indexOf("#");if(e>=0){var a=_gjwl.href.substring(e);if(a.indexOf("&q=")>0||a.indexOf("#q=")>=0){a=a.substring(1);if(a.indexOf("#")==-1){for(var c=0;c<a.length;){var d=c;if(a.charAt(d)=="&")++d;var b=a.indexOf("&",d);if(b==-1)b=a.length;var f=a.substring(d,b);if(f.indexOf("fp=")==0){a=a.substring(0,c)+a.substring(b,a.length);b=c}else if(f=="cad=h")return 0;c=b}_gjwl.href="/search?"+a+"&cad=h";return 1}}}return 0}function _gjp(){!(window._gjwl.hash&&
window._gjuc())&&setTimeout(_gjp,500)};
window._gjp && _gjp()</script><style id=gstyle>body{margin:0}#gog{padding:3px 8px 0}td{line-height:.8em}.gac_m td{line-height:17px}form{margin-bottom:20px}body,td,a,p,.h{font-family:arial,sans-serif}.h{color:#36c;font-size:20px}.q{color:#00c}.ts td{padding:0}.ts{border-collapse:collapse}em{font-weight:bold;font-style:normal}.lst{width:496px}.tiah{width:458px}input{font-family:inherit}a.gb1,a.gb2,a.gb3,a.gb4{color:#11c !important}#gbar,#guser{font-size:13px;padding-top:1px !important}#gbar{height:22px}#guser{padding-bottom:7px !important;text-align:right}.gbh,.gbd{border-top:1px solid #c9d7f1;font-size:1px}.gbh{height:0;position:absolute;top:24px;width:100%}@media all{.gb1{height:22px;margin-right:.5em;vertical-align:top}#gbar{float:left}}a.gb1,a.gb4{color:#00c !important}body{background:#fff;color:black}input{-moz-box-sizing:content-box}a{color:#11c;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:active{text-decoration:underline}.fl a{color:#4272db}a:visited{color:#551a8b}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline}a.gb3:hover{text-decoration:none}#ghead a.gb2:hover{color:#fff!important}.ds{display:-moz-inline-box}.ds{border-bottom:solid 1px #e7e7e7;border-right:solid 1px #e7e7e7;display:inline-block;margin:3px 0 4px;margin-left:4px}.sblc{padding-top:5px}.sblc a{display:block;margin:2px 0;margin-left:13px;font-size:11px;}.lsbb{background:#eee;border:solid 1px;border-color:#ccc #999 #999 #ccc;height:30px;display:block}.lsb{background:url(/images/srpr/nav_logo14.png) bottom;font:15px arial,sans-serif;border:none;color:#000;cursor:pointer;height:30px;margin:0;outline:0;vertical-align:top}.lsb:active{background:#ccc}.lst:focus{outline:none}.ftl,#fll a{margin:0 12px}#addlang a{padding:0 3px}.gac_v div{display:none}.gac_v .gac_v2,.gac_bt{display:block!important}</style><script>google.y={};google.x=function(e,g){google.y[e.id]=[e,g];return false};</script></head><body bgcolor=#ffffff text=#000000 link=#0000cc vlink=#551a8b alink=#ff0000 onload="document.f.q.focus();if(document.images)new Image().src='/images/srpr/nav_logo14.png'" ><textarea id=csi style=display:none></textarea><div id=ghead><div id=gbar><nobr><b class=gb1>Web</b> <a onclick=gbar.qs(this) href="http://www.google.co.uk/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi" class=gb1>Images</a> <a onclick=gbar.qs(this) href="http://video.google.co.uk/?hl=en&tab=wv" class=gb1>Videos</a> <a onclick=gbar.qs(this) href="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?hl=en&tab=wl" class=gb1>Maps</a> <a onclick=gbar.qs(this) href="http://news.google.co.uk/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn" class=gb1>News</a> <a onclick=gbar.qs(this) href="http://www.google.co.uk/prdhp?hl=en&tab=wf" class=gb1>Shopping</a> <a href="http://mail.google.com/mail/?hl=en&tab=wm" class=gb1>Gmail</a> <a href="http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en/options/" class=gb1 style="text-decoration:none"><u>more</u> &raquo;</a></nobr></div><div id=guser width=100%><nobr><span id=gbn class=gbi></span><span id=gbf class=gbf></span><span id=gbe><a href="/url?sa=p&pref=ig&pval=3&q=http://www.google.co.uk/ig%3Fhl%3Den%26source%3Diglk&usg=AFQjCNH9dUJQAsNWnO3XKq2EIPgFbczqlA" class=gb4>iGoogle</a> | </span><a href="/preferences?hl=en" class=gb4>Settings</a> | <a href="https://www.google.com/accounts/Login?hl=en&continue=http://www.google.co.uk/" class=gb4>Sign in</a></nobr></div><div class=gbh style=left:0></div><div class=gbh style=right:0></div></div> <center><br clear=all id=lgpd><div id=lga><div style="padding:28px 0 3px"><div align=left style="background:url(/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png) no-repeat;height:110px;width:276px" title="Google" id=logo onload="window.lol&&lol()"><div nowrap style="color:#777;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;left:214px;position:relative;top:70px">UK</div></div></div><br></div><form action="/search" name=f><table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr valign=top><td width=25%>&nbsp;</td><td align=center nowrap><input name=hl type=hidden value=en><input name=source type=hidden value=hp><input type=hidden name=ie value="ISO-8859-1"><div class=ds style="height:32px;margin:4px 0"><input autocomplete="off" maxlength=2048 name=q class="lst" title="Google Search" value="" size=57 style="background:#fff;border:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom-color:#999;border-right-color:#999;color:#000;font:18px arial,sans-serif bold;height:25px;margin:0;padding:5px 8px 0 6px;vertical-align:top"></div><br style="line-height:0"><span class=ds ><span class=lsbb><input name=btnG type=submit value="Google Search" class=lsb></span></span><span class=ds><span class=lsbb><input name=btnI type=submit value="I&#39;m Feeling Lucky" class=lsb></span></span></td><td nowrap width=25% align=left class=sblc><a href="/advanced_search?hl=en">Advanced Search</a><a href="/language_tools?hl=en">Language Tools</a></td></tr></table></form><div style="font-size:83%;min-height:3.5em"><br></div><div id=res></div><span id=footer><center id=fctr><div style="font-size:10pt"><div id=fll style="margin:19px auto 19px auto;text-align:center"><a href="/intl/en/ads/">Advertising&nbsp;Programmes</a><a href="/services/">Business Solutions</a><a href="/intl/en/about.html">About Google</a><a href="http://www.google.com/ncr">Go to Google.com</a></div></div><p style="color:#767676;font-size:8pt">&copy; 2010 - <a href="/intl/en/privacy.html">Privacy</a></p></center></span> <div id=xjsd></div><div id=xjsi><script>if(google.y)google.y.first=[];if(google.y)google.y.first=[];google.dstr=[];google.rein=[];window.setTimeout(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.src="/extern_js/f/CgJlbhICdWsgACswRTgBLCswWjgALCswDjgALCswFzgALCswJzgELCswPDgALCswCjhzQB0sKzAWOAAsKzAlOM-IASwrMEA4EywrMEE4BSwrMFQ4ASwrMBg4ACwrMCY4DiyAAheQAhs/N_JFQ4PkHl4.js";(document.getElementById("xjsd")||document.body).appendChild(a);if(google.timers&&google.timers.load.t)google.timers.load.t.xjsls=(new Date).getTime();},0);
google.neegg=1;google.y.first.push(function(){var form=document.f||document.f||document.gs;google.ac.i(form,form.q,'','','',{o:1,sw:1,r:0});google.mc = [[14,{}],[22,{"m_error":"<font color=red>Error:</font> The server could not complete your request.  Try again in 30 seconds.","m_tip":"Click for more information"}],[64,{}]];google.med('init');google.History&&google.History.initialize('/')});if(google.j&&google.j.en&&google.j.xi){window.setTimeout(google.j.xi,0);google.fade=null;}</script></div><script>(function(){
var b,d,e,f;function g(a,c){if(a.removeEventListener){a.removeEventListener("load",c,false);a.removeEventListener("error",c,false)}else{a.detachEvent("onload",c);a.detachEvent("onerror",c)}}function h(a){f=(new Date).getTime();++d;a=a||window.event;var c=a.target||a.srcElement;g(c,h)}var i=document.getElementsByTagName("img");b=i.length;d=0;for(var j=0,k;j<b;++j){k=i[j];if(k.complete||typeof k.src!="string"||!k.src)++d;else if(k.addEventListener){k.addEventListener("load",h,false);k.addEventListener("error",
h,false)}else{k.attachEvent("onload",h);k.attachEvent("onerror",h)}}e=b-d;function l(){if(!google.timers.load.t)return;google.timers.load.t.ol=(new Date).getTime();google.timers.load.t.iml=f;google.kCSI.imc=d;google.kCSI.imn=b;google.kCSI.imp=e;google.timers.load.t.xjs&&google.report&&google.report(google.timers.load,google.kCSI)}if(window.addEventListener)window.addEventListener("load",l,false);else if(window.attachEvent)window.attachEvent("onload",l);google.timers.load.t.prt=(f=(new Date).getTime());
})();
</script>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why would you assume that something would be printed without a `'print'` statement?

Comment: The debug flag should print the headers as shown in his question. This specific example is from the `diveintopython` tutorial and it seems to be flawed.

Comment: Thank you, WoLpH.  I didn't know that.  I cut & pasted the code and ran it myself and got the same result.  Adding the print did the trick.

Comment: How it differed from what I expect is that it didn't print out any of the headers, it did nothing. With debuglvel = 1 where WoLpH suggested I got what I wanted. Thank you for that coding, WolpH. Also, as WoLpH says, the code in Dive Into Python does appear to be flawed.